# what is diffrent '<<' and 'push' in Ruby Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, push

```rb
array = []
array << true ? "O" : "X"
```

i did expect to `["O"]`.
but `array` is `[true]`

and now i use `push`

```
array.push(true ? "O" : "X")
```

then result is `["O"]`

actually `true ? "O" : "X"` return to `"O"`
my assumption was `["O"]` if use `<<` and `push` both. but it's not.
anybody known why?

Comment: It's about precedence. As you see, `<<` has higher precedence than ternary operator. `array << (true ? '0' : 'X')` will work as you expect.

Comment: `<<` is just a method. you can call it like that `array.<<(true ? "O" : "X")`.
difference between push is only that push can accept multiple arguments `push *args`, but `<<` only 1

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize the how the Ruby parser is seeing your 2 expressions using [ruby_parser](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser) gem.

```
require 'ruby_parser'
require 'pp'

pp RubyParser.new.parse 'true ? "O" : "X"'
# => s(:if, s(:true), s(:str, "O"), s(:str, "X"))
```

Now, based on the above parsing result, compare this :

```
pp RubyParser.new.parse '[] << true ? "O" : "X"'
# => s(:if, s(:call, s(:array), :<<, s(:true)), s(:str, "O"), s(:str, "X"))
#                    <-----------------------> look this part
```

And then,

```
pp RubyParser.new.parse '[].push(true ? "O" : "X")'
# => s(:call, s(:array), :push, s(:if, s(:true), s(:str, "O"), s(:str, "X")))
```